# How to overcome Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG in Jenkins?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium 2.47.1 & TestNG for automation process. I'm using Jenkins for continuous integration. Jenkins is installed in Linux server. Jenkins workspace directory is given below : `/home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes`

I have stored lib files in another location. lib files are stored in following path `/home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/lib`

I am using following Shell Command to run Job
`java -cp /home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/lib/*:/home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes/bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

Whenever I am trying above Shell Command to run Jenkins job, I'm getting following error `[TestNG] [ERROR] 
Cannot instantiate class eNotes.ENotes`

How to solve this problem...?

Comment: Why do you have "./home" if the directory is "/home"? Do you suppose `java` will be run from "/"?

Comment: I'm getting following error while using "/home". Error message is given below `[TestNG] [ERROR] 
Cannot instantiate class eNotes.ENotes`

Comment: Maybe, but the described problem is fixed and now it is another one ;) You should reword the question

Comment: Which testng version are you using? Could you share your testng.xml? Where is located ENotes.class?

Comment: I am using testng-6.8.5.jar. testng.xml file is given below :                   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="eNotes.ENotes"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->`     ENotes class present in the given file `/home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes/src/eNotes/ENotes.java`

Comment: Ok for the java file but verify class file.

Comment: @juherr It's worked for me now.... I have modified the class files & fixed the issue.. Thank you very much for your help...